# How to select all occurrences of phone numbers inside specific div with regex, and replace them with new code using jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

Let say I have div with next content

```
<body> <div id="mydiv">This is some number +387(0)61 833-312. Here is one more number +385 (95) 837 312 . <p> One more number here +385(95) 835-312</p> <p>One more number 061/665-151</p>One more phone: 061-353-654</p></div> </body>
```

I need jquery with regex which will on document load replace every phone number with:

```
<span class="telefon" data-last="PHONENUMBER"><span class="telefon2">click here to show</span></span>
```

So the output would be:

```
<body>
<div id="mydiv">This is some number <span class="telefon" data-last="+387(0)61 833-312"><span class="telefon2">click here to show</span></span>. Here is one more number <span class="telefon" data-last="+385 (95) 837 312"><span class="telefon2">click here to show</span></span> <p> One more number here <span class="telefon" data-last="+385(95) 835-312"><span class="telefon2">click here to show</span></span></p> <p>One more number <span class="telefon" data-last="061/665-151"><span class="telefon2">click here to show</span></span> </p>One more phone: <span class="telefon" data-last="061-353-654"><span class="telefon2">click here to show</span></span></p></div>
</body>
```

Here is regex I build:

```
/[+]{0,1}[\d]{1,4}[\s]{0,1}[/]{0,1}[(]{0,1}[\d]{0,3}[)]{0,1}\s{0,1}\d{2,4}[-]{0,1}[\s]{0,1}[\d]{2,4}[-]{0,1}[\s]{0,1}[\d]{1,4}/gm
```

I already have this jquery in my code, and I need to run this solution before this code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.telefon').toggle(function() {
    $(this).find('span').text('Click to show');
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('span').text($(this).data('last'));
  }).click();
});
```

.telefon class actually exists in html code.

EDIT: Pedro Lobito provided solution for first part, but how can I execute Pedro Lobito code before this code above? I have tried putting his code below this, but regex is not runing, I mean it output $1, and not html code we wrote.

Comment: Welcome to `SO`. You are invited to share your source code, *attempts* and specific questions (where did you get stuck?). Just dumping your requirements is not within the scope of this community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```js
result = $('#mydiv').prop('outerHTML').replace(/(?!\s|\/)([\d\+\(\)\s\/-]+)/mg, '<span class="telefon" data-last="$1"><span class="telefon2">click here to show</span></span>');

$("#mydiv").html(result);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">
This is some number +387(0)61 833-312. Here is one more number +385 (95) 837 312 . <p> One more number here +385(95) 835-312</p> <p>One more number 061/665-151</p>One more phone: 061-353-654</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Notes:**

1. The regex worked  with every phonumber present on the
   provided string, but may not work with further examples.
2. [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/z44iZn/1)

Comment: Thanks, it works just fine.

Reason I need this code is to track clicks on phone numbers with google analytics events.

Comment: Dear Pedro, can you help me run your code before my other jquery code on document load? I posted my other jquery code in other answer. Thank you.

Comment: I have realized that I need to do this in php, on server side and not jquery. Second part, can be done with jquery. So, thanks again Pedro, you answered correctly to my original question. I apologize to admins if my question was not written exactly in line with forum rules .

Comment: It happens, GL!